# Selenium scrapes only one result and ignores other related reults

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am new to selenium. Searching a web site, I get 10 results for each page. Those results are shown as lists (li tags) on the page and each list contains the same attributes. When my conditions are met, I go to another related web page and get desired content. However, when my code keeps looping for the lists, it fails to find the same attributes for the others. Here is my code:

```
        p_url = "https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?keywords=BARCO%2BNV%2Bkortrijk&pt=people&page_num=5"             
        driver.get(p_url)

        time.sleep(5)

        results = driver.find_element_by_id("results-container")
        employees = results.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

        #emp_list = []
        #for i in range(len(employees)):
        #    emp_list.append(employees[i])


        for emp in employees:
            try:

                main_emp = emp.find_element_by_css_selector("a.title.main-headline")
                name = emp.find_element_by_css_selector("a.title.main-headline").text
                href = main_emp.get_attribute("href")

                if name != "LinkedIn Member":
                    location = emp.find_element_by_class_name("demographic").text
                    href = main_emp.get_attribute("href")
                    print(href)
                    print(location)

                    driver.get(href)
                    exp = driver.find_element_by_id("background-experience")

                    amkk = exp.find_elements_by_class_name("editable-item")

                    for amk in amkk:
                        him = amk.find_element_by_tag_name("header").text
                        him2 = amk.find_element_by_class_name("experience-date-locale").text

                        if '\n' in him:
                            a = him.split('\n')
                            print(a[0])
                            print(a[1])

                        print(him2)

            except Exception as exc:
                print(exc)
                continue
```

In this code the line `main_emp = emp.find_element_by_css_selector("a.title.main-headline")` stop working after it works for the first time. As a result I got an error of `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

From stackoverflow questions I saw that some say the content is removed from DOM structure and from another post someone suggested to fill a list with the results. Here what I have tried `emp_list = []
        for i in range(len(employees)):
            emp_list.append(employees[i])` , however, it also did not work out.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Could you share the HTML you are using? I just checked the page you go to and when I go to the `results-container` `div` there is not a single `li` that is direct child of this element, yet you say it works for the first employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you are using is wrong. You are getting the results using the `results-container` id. This works fine, but the collecting the elements form this is not working. It is returning more elements than just the employees (I'm not quite sure why).

If you change you selectors to this single selector you will get just the employees and no other unwanted elements.

```
employees = results.find_elements_by_css_selector("ol[id='results']>li")
```

**Edit**
Since you are opening the employees and losing the list of elements you might want to try opening the employee in a new tab, perform your actions here and close the tab afterwards.

Example:

```
    for emp in employees:
            try:
                    main_emp = emp.find_element_by_css_selector("a.title.main-headline")
                    # Do stuff you need...

                    # Open employee in new tab (make sure Keys is imported)
                    main_emp.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
                    # Focus on new tab
                    driver.switch_to_window(d.window_handles[1])

                    # Do stuff inside the employee page
                    # Close the tab you opened
                    driver.close()
                    # Switch back to the first tab
                    driver.switch_to_window(d.window_handles[0])
```

**Note:** For `OSX` you should use `main_emp.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer RemcoW. However, I still have the same issue. In the related web page this code works for the 3rd member and get the content. In the same page the code msut work for the 4th member. But I have still `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` error. My guess is that inside the loop I  go to the member profile page and when this happens all the info kept by `employees` is lost.

Comment: @mlee_jordan Yep, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: @mlee_jordan Check my new edit. This might help you.